# How to find out the cause of hanging software? (problem with qemu + zephyr + tfm)

Tags: debugging, arm, gdb, reverse-engineering, interrupt

I'm executing an arm elf (zephyr os + tfm) on qemu and make it run some tests.
Unfortunately, it stops at a certain point without either an error message or warnings.
I also tried with GDB, but at a certain point, it just stops.
It always stops at the same point for the same version (if I add some debug prints it stop earlier or later).
I think there is some pending interrupt that simply is not caught... no idea honestly.

Thus, my question: How to find out the cause of hanging software?
Or also, how can I check which interrupt has been risen to stop the normal execution?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference `TF-M` has an option to enable an exception info dump print in case of faults. I would start enabling that by setting the following define in the `cmake` config step: `-DTFM_EXCEPTION_INFO_DUMP=True`